# Can I use my @me.com address as my primary email address?

Tags: email

Is my @me.com address a good candidate for my primary email address?
I'd like to stop using my old yahoo address.
I also only use Mac products. (MacBook, iPhone, iPad).

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  What does it mean to be a "good candidate for [your] primary email address"?

Comment: Just forward all your existing mail from Yahoo to @me (or @icloud.com) and login with your iCloud data?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Sorry, this question has no definitive answer and would only lead to subjective answers. Feel free to use whatever e-mail address you like.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. iCloud has a good online email client and supports IMAP for clients like Outlook or Thunderbird.

However, you might want to use the new @icloud.com email alias.

Comment: +1 It even supports *secure* (well, at least SSL) IMAP and SMTP, see this: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4864

Answer (score 1):

Apple discontinued the @me.com email addresses a couple of months ago. You can still receive emails from @me.com, @mac.com, and @icloud.com, but can only send from @icloud.com I believe.